# openssl version in electron

Tags: openssl, electron, chromium, boringssl

As per electron documents electron does not use openssl but it uses BoringSSL. I created an electron app using electron v8.2.5 and in the debugging console window I executed `process.versions.openssl`. I can see the openssl version as `1.1.0`. Also I downloaded the the electron zip from https://github.com/electron/electron/releases/download/v8.2.5/electron-v8.2.5-darwin-x64.zip and did black duck binary analysis. There also I can see the openssl version as 1.1.0. If electron does not use openssl, then which openssl version is this? Is this version, the openssl version from which BoringSSL was forked?

Comment: BoringSSL is Google's OpenSSL clone which was forked in 2014. By that time, OpenSSL was at v. 1.0.1, so I suspect that the version Electron returns is the version of OpenSSL BoringSSL is compatible with, but I'm not sure on that.